# does someone know a good educational sample about use mef with controllers?

Tags: c#, mvvm, prism, mef, controllers

I'm looking for an example to teach me about using MEF and controllers in Silerlight.

I was seeing StockTraderRI from PRISM examples, but that one looks a little difficult for me to understand all the structure of the program.

So do you know a website that shows example samples about MEF and controllers?

Comment: using mef in mvc (msdn link) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh708870(v=vs.110).aspx  Mef let you have only to import export method